# Understand moveToPoint and addLineToPoint methods of UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

My main purpose is of creating a line which has origin point at center of other UIBezierPath which is ROUND in look.

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2)

    println("Start Angle \(startAngle) , End Angle \(endAngle)")

    let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)

    self.staticLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath

    self.staticLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.staticLayer.shouldRasterize = false

    self.staticLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    self.staticLayer.lineWidth = 08
    self.staticLayer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.staticLayer.borderWidth = 5.0

    layer.addSublayer(self.staticLayer)
```

After this static layer, I want to add a line (same as seconds in clock)

I made it

```
  var bezierPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.staticLayer.position.x/2, y: self.staticLayer.position.y/2))
    bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 10))


    self.lineLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath

    self.lineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.lineLayer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    self.lineLayer.shouldRasterize = false
    self.lineLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    self.lineLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel

    layer.addSublayer(self.lineLayer)
```

Now, I am unable to understand exact passing points of **moveToPoint** and **addLineToPoint**.

I want to start this from center of other layer, which is static and round in shape.

**Can any one explain me, how can I control starting point and length of line?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) :

```
moveToPoint:
```

> This method implicitly ends the current subpath (if any) and sets the
>   current point to the value in the point parameter. When ending the
>   previous subpath, this method does not actually close the subpath.
>   Therefore, the first and last points of the previous subpath are not
>   connected to each other.
>
> For many path operations, you must call this method before issuing any
>   commands that cause a line or curve segment to be drawn.

This means : take the "pen" up, and move it without drawing to a specified point. This point will be a starting point for next drawing operation.

```
addLineToPoint:
```

> This method creates a straight line segment starting at the current
>   point and ending at the point specified by the point parameter. After
>   adding the line segment, this method updates the current point to the
>   value in point.
>
> You must set the path’s current point (using the moveToPoint: method
>   or through the previous creation of a line or curve segment) before
>   you call this method. If the path is empty, this method does nothing.

This will "draw" a line, from current point to a specified point. The end of line will become the new starting point.

---

It seems that your positioning problem is in this line :

```
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.staticLayer.position.x/2, y: self.staticLayer.position.y/2))
```

The position of a layer are the coordinates of its top-left corner in parent space. So if you specify the starting point like that, you are actually starting somewhere "outside" of it. Also the points are specfied in "this" layers coordinates, so the center point should be `(width / 2, height / 2)` of the layer to which you will be applying your bezier path.

Comment: I have read this already from apple documents. but it is not working accordingly. I think I am setting wrong points. Look into code for a while and check what should be exact moveToPath and addLineToPath Rects so it could start from center of other UIBezierPoint.

Comment: I can't accept Q if you copy and paste from apple documents. Kindly elaborate properly so I could achieve my target. I would appreciate it.

Comment: If it is like this, as apple said, why it is not coming in center of other BeZierPath????? Can you tell me co-ordinate mistakes.

Comment: I am changing moveToPoint , but it is changing height. So, it is not starting point in my sense. I have to sort out exact use of this. Either it is layers issue, my parent layer?

Comment: I know it is position issue, but what position should I set to make it fix ;)

Comment: I'd try doing it the same way you did before here : `let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)`, taking the frame from `lineLayer`

Comment: It is coming in center, but it is end point, not start point of UIBezeirPath. means if you rotate this line, it will move center position which you set.

Comment: and it is not 90 degree, like a clocks starts from 12am . like this |

Comment: It's not straight because you draw the line to `(50, 10)` :) If you want a straight line, you should draw it to `(width / 2, 0)` This will give you a straight line up to the top of the layer. Also, I'd suggest rotating the whole layer, rather than redrawing the line every time.

Comment: It is done, looking nice, but issue is that it is not rotating from center. I am accepting your answer. I hope you would edit this too.

Comment: I will be away from computer for some time, but will check this later today :)

Comment: I want to rotate this, but origin center piont must be fix, and it must rotate, same as seconds do..... I will show you my code too.

Comment: Ok, so I've checked, and center point stays fixed. You can achieve rotation with this line : `lineLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 1)` - the first argument is the angle in radians, the 3 last is the vector about which to rotate. With `0, 0, 1` you will get rotation about the `z` axis.