# Swift CoreGraphics UIBezierPath will not fill interior correctly

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, topojson

I'm trying to draw countries and fill the interior a certain color. My data source is a [TopoJSON](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/wiki/Introduction#example) file, which, in a nutshell, is made up of shapes that reference an array of arcs to create a shape. I convert this into an array of `paths`, which I then iterate through to draw the country. As you can see in the below screenshot, I'm drawing the correct lines of the outline of the country (Afghanistan).

[image: Afghanistan Outline]

However, when I try to use `path.fill()`, I end up getting the following. Note how the black lines are correct, but the colors go outside and inside haphazardly.

[image: Afghanistan filled]

**Code**

```
var mapRegion = MapRegion()
var path = mapRegion.createPath()
var origin: CGPoint = .zero

geometry.paths
    .enumerated()
    .forEach { (geoIndex, shape) in

        shape
            .enumerated()
            .forEach { (shapeIndex, coord) in

                guard let coordPoint = coord.double else { return }
                let values = coordinatesToGraphics(x: coordPoint.x, y: coordPoint.y)
                let point = CGPoint(x: values.x, y: values.y)

                if origin == .zero {
                    origin = point
                }

                // Shape is about to be closed
                if shapeIndex != 0 && path.contains(point) {

                    // Close, save path (2)
                    path.addLine(to: origin)
                    // (3) path.close()
                    mapRegion.savePath()

                    // Add to map, reset process
                    canvas.layer.addSublayer(mapRegion)
                    mapRegions.append(mapRegion)
                    mapRegion = MapRegion()
                    path = mapRegion.createPath()

                 }

                 else {
                     if shapeIndex == 0 {
                         path.move(to: point)
                     } else {
                         path.addLine(to: point)
                     }
                 }



             }

}
```

I've tried exhaustively messing with [`usesEvenOddFillRule`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624360-usesevenoddfillrule) ([further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule)), but nothing ever changes. I found that Comment (1) above helped resolve an issue where borders were being drawn that shouldn't be. The function `savePath()` at (2) runs the `setStroke()`, `stroke()`, `setFill()`, `fill()` functions.

**Update:** `path.close()` draws a line that closes the path at the bottom-left corner of the shape, instead of the top-left corner where it first starts drawing. That function closes the "most recently added subpath", but how are subpaths defined?

I can't say for sure whether the problem is my logic or some CoreGraphics trick. I have a collection of paths that I need to stitch together and treat as one, and I believe I'm doing that. I've looked at the data points, and the end of one arc to the beginning of the next are identical. I printed the path I stitch together and I basically `move(to:)` the same point, so there are no duplicates when I `addLine(to:)` Looking at the way the simulator is coloring the region, I first guessed maybe the individual arcs were being treated as shapes, but there are only 6 arcs in this example, and several more inside-outside color switches.

I'd really appreciate any help here!

Comment: Have you tried adding lines directly to the `path` instead of creating many individual paths? In this approach you'd only use move to move to the origin (not once for each shape as you're presently doing).

Comment: I'm moving towards that. Sometimes paths can be islands that are part of a region, so I'm making a mechanism to check when the path arrives back at the start, and then to close it up and fill it.

Comment: @featherless I'm now creating one path only, and I'm getting the same result :/

Comment: What does the updated code look like?

Comment: Below. I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that using `path.move(to:)` creates a **subpath** within the `UIBezierPath()`, which the fill algorithm seemingly treats as separate, multiple paths ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154142/understand-movetopoint-and-addlinetopoint-methods-of-uibezierpath) that led to discovery). The solution was to remove the extra, unnecessary `move(to:)` calls. Below is the working code and happy result! Thanks!

```
var mapRegion = MapRegion()
var path = mapRegion.createPath()
path.move(to: .zero)
var pointsDictionary: [String: Bool] = [:]

geometry.paths
  .enumerated()
  .forEach { (geoIndex, shape) in

      shape
          .enumerated()
          .forEach { (shapeIndex, coord) in

              guard let coordPoint = coord.double else { return }
              let values = coordinatesToGraphics(x: coordPoint.x, y: coordPoint.y)
              let point = CGPoint(x: values.x, y: values.y)

              // Move to start
              if path.currentPoint == .zero {
                  path.move(to: point)
              }

              if shapeIndex != 0 {

                  // Close shape
                  if pointsDictionary[point.debugDescription] ?? false {

                      // Close path, set colors, save
                      mapRegion.save(path)
                      regionDrawer.drawPath(of: mapRegion)

                      // Reset process
                      canvas.layer.addSublayer(mapRegion)
                      mapRegions.append(mapRegion)
                      mapRegion = MapRegion()
                      path = mapRegion.createPath()
                      pointsDictionary = [:]

                  }

                  // Add to shape
                  else {
                      path.addLine(to: point)
                  }

              }

      }

}
```

[image]

Comment: On a global scale, this solution is hella slow. Working to optimize it more!

Comment: Using a dictionary over an array to store past points did the trick!